# Finding Explicit Form of Function Defined by Definite Integral

Tags: real-analysis, integration, ordinary-differential-equations

Let

$$f(y) = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} e^{-x^2} \cos (xy) \> dx$$

One can show that

$$f'(y) = - \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}xe^{-x^2}  \sin (xy) \> dx$$

I'm interested in making an ODE involving $f$ and its derivative and then solving this ODE to get an explicit form for $f$.

I have that

$$f'(y) =  \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} x e^{-x^2} \cos (\frac{\pi}{2} + xy) \> 
dx$$

but am still unsure how to make an ODE out of this.

Comment: Your first equation *is* explicit form of $f(y)$. If, on the other hand, you meant *closed form*...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Integrating by parts, with $u = \sin(xy)$ and $dv = x e^{-x^2}$, we find:

$$f'(y) = -\frac{y}2 f(y)$$

Showing:

$$f(y) = f(0) e^{-y^2/4} = \sqrt{\pi} e^{-y^2/4}$$

Answer (score 1):

Ahmed Hussein has an answer which is more in the spirit of the question but alternatively, we could define \begin{align*} g(y) &= \int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{-x^2} e^{ixy}dx = \int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{-x^2+ixy}dx \\&= \int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{-(x+iy/2)^2} e^{-y^2/4}dx \\ &= e^{-y^2/4} \int^{\infty}_{-\infty}e^{-(x+iy/2)^2} dx.\end{align*} It is easy to show that $\int^{\infty}_{-\infty}e^{-(x+iy/2)^2} dx = \int^{\infty}_{-\infty}e^{-x^2} dx$ for any $y \in \mathbb R$ by taking a large rectangular contour in the complex plane. Then $f(y) = \text{Re}(g(y)) = g(y) = \sqrt \pi e^{-y^2/4}$.

Comment: Your answer is quite nice but seems difficult to see before knowing the answer

Answer (score 0):

We can also find the ODE using Taylor series and the functional equation of the Gamma function. We have $$f\left(y\right)=\sum_{k\geq0}\frac{\left(-1\right)^{k}}{\left(2k\right)!}y^{2k}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}e^{-x^{2}}x^{2k}dx=2\sum_{k\geq0}\frac{\left(-1\right)^{k}}{\left(2k\right)!}y^{2k}\int_{0}^{\infty}e^{-x^{2}}x^{2k}dx
 $$ $$\stackrel{x^{2}=u}{=}\sum_{k\geq0}\frac{\left(-1\right)^{k}}{\left(2k\right)!}y^{2k}\int_{0}^{\infty}e^{-u}u^{k-1/2}du=\sum_{k\geq0}\frac{\left(-1\right)^{k}}{\left(2k\right)!}y^{2k}\Gamma\left(k+\frac{1}{2}\right)
 $$ and similary $$f'\left(y\right)=-\sum_{k\geq0}\frac{\left(-1\right)^{k}}{\left(2k+1\right)!}y^{2k+1}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}e^{-x^{2}}x^{2k+2}dx=-\sum_{k\geq0}\frac{\left(-1\right)^{k}}{\left(2k+1\right)!}y^{2k+1}\int_{0}^{\infty}e^{-u}u^{k+1/2}du
 $$ $$=-\sum_{k\geq0}\frac{\left(-1\right)^{k}}{\left(2k+1\right)!}y^{2k+1}\Gamma\left(k+\frac{3}{2}\right)=-\sum_{k\geq0}\frac{\left(-1\right)^{k}}{2\left(2k\right)!}y^{2k+1}\Gamma\left(k+\frac{1}{2}\right)=-\frac{y}{2}f\left(y\right).
 $$ Now if we want to calculate the integral we don't need to solve the ODE. We may note, recalling that $$\Gamma\left(k+\frac{1}{2}\right)=\frac{\sqrt{\pi}\left(2k-1\right)!!}{2^{k}}=\frac{\sqrt{\pi}\left(2k\right)!}{2^{2k}k!}
 $$ which follows from the duplication formula of Gamma and the properties of the double factorial, that$$f\left(y\right)=\sum_{k\geq0}\frac{\left(-1\right)^{k}}{\left(2k\right)!}y^{2k}\Gamma\left(k+\frac{1}{2}\right)=\sqrt{\pi}\sum_{k\geq0}\frac{\left(-1\right)^{k}}{\left(2k\right)!}y^{2k}\frac{\left(2k-1\right)!!}{2^{k}}
 $$ $$=\sqrt{\pi}\sum_{k\geq0}\frac{1}{k!}\left(-\frac{y^{2}}{4}\right)^{k}=\color{red}{\frac{\sqrt{\pi}}{e^{y^{2}/4}}}.$$